# Android autostart application

Tags: android, service, device, boot, autostart

How can I autostart my application's service at device boot (with the possibility of enabling/disabling this feature)? What permissions do I have to include in AndroidManifest?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this permission are use

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

In your <application> element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.example;

public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

for more help :: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/
                 http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82
                 http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/starting-android-service-at-boot-time.html