# Autostart app immediately after the boot

Tags: android, boot, autostart

I want to start my application when phone startup

I just follow tutorial from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317939/android-autostart-application) but it doesn't work in my device. Please see my method:

```
package net.londatiga.android;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    } 
}
```

And this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.londatiga.android"
      android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.01">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

         <receiver android:name="net.londatiga.android.MyBroadcastReceiver"  
     android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>

        <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where is my mistake please?

Comment: Have you started ExampleActivity before the reboot? At least one Activity has to be started by the user in order to BOOT_COMPLETED intent be delivered by the system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
 context.startService(startServiceIntent);
```

Use:

```
 context.startActivity(startServiceIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Service, You need to open activity.

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);

context.startActivity(startServiceIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class name it as **AfterBootActivity**:

```
  public class AfterBootActivity extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
}}
```

Now, Create a new class named as **Autostart.java** which extends a **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {          
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StarterService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
}}
```

In the Manifest file add this class as a receiver. This class will listen to the Broadcast call the Android OS sends after the boot sequence has finished i.e. after the phone started up.

Now Create a class named as **StarterService.java** which will extend Service:

```
 public class StarterService extends Service {
   private static final String TAG = "MyService";
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

/**
 * The below started service opens the Activity.
 */

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AfterBootActivity.class);
    intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intents);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}}
```

When the class Autostart receives the BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast from Android OS it will start the StarterService which then starts the Android Activity “AfterBootActivity” i.e our main class. We can play any audio/video or anything in it.

Change your **Manifest.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="on.boot.completed"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="on.boot.completed.AfterBootActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="on.boot.completed.Autostart" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="on.boot.completed.StarterService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also Remember to install it in internal memory because if the app installed on the SD Card then autostart will not work! That’s why it’s important that we add in manifest.

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

That’s all run your app. 
After it has been started turn off your phone and turn it back on and the app would start automatically after the device has booted up.